# ld cannot find library curl when running make file

Tags: curl, makefile, linker, centos7, ld

When compiling using a prebuilt make file that was given to me, I encountered the following error:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [dis.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'intg_builds/Test2'
```

From what I understand, the linker failed to find the curl file when linking. Upon search through the file system I found curl in /usr/bin/, and a symbolic link to it in /bin/. Curl was even in the same directory as ld.

Here is the code from the make file where it was linking to curl:

```
EXTRALIBS= /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a -lcurl
```

The operating system is Centos 7 64-bit.

Curl is version 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcur/7.29.0 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3

Xerces-c is version 3.1.1

Where should I have a symbolic link to curl for the linker to find it properly?

Please note: It is discouraged for me to alter the make files at this point in time. It would be better for my purposes if we could replicate the environment that this make file was made for.

More information:
In /usr/lib64/ there are 2 libcurl.so files. One is "libcurl.so.4" and the other is "libcurl.so.4.3.0"

Update:
After a suggestion to install libcurl-devel, the errors have changed. Now I am getting hundreds of undefined reference errors in the same package. Examples follow:

```
/home/~/Downloads/git/Foo/Build_Tools/HLA/trunk/xerces-c/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/./sercesc/util/RefHashTableOf.c:415: undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a(IGXMLScanner2.o):/home/~/Downloads/git/Foo/Build_Tools/HLA/trunk/xerces-c/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/./xercesc/util/RefHashTableOf.c:223: more undefined references to 'operator delete(void*, unsigned long)' follow
```

They seem to reference either delete, or `uset_<Bar>_50` which look like properties or global variables, transcoder functions and variables and the like. It almost feels like it's trying to connect to the wrong library.

Answer (score 0):

> /bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl

`-lcurl` means 'libcurl.**so**' and you've only got the run time lib `libcurl.so.4 ->   libcurl.so.4.3.0`

`# yum install libcurl-devel` : Provides files for building apps with `curl` →

`/usr/bin/curl-config, /usr/include/curl/{headers.h}, /usr/lib64/libcurl.so, /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc`

Comment: So are you saying that neither libcurl.so.4 and libcurl.so.4.3.0 are the right library for this? If so, thanks. I'll try it when I get to work, and if so I'll accept this, and if possible amend the question title to be more easily found by others.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment now, but this did not correct the problem. Instead now I am getting undefined references to various functions in curl. I will update my question with some examples.

Comment: May be some limitations in your code. Suggestions: **1**. Use the binary version from CentOS6. **2**. Upload the code (dropbox, GoogleDrive) → show a **shared** link, and I will try ceating an rpm, usable in CentOS7. (I have ~60 different OS´s to test / create applications and binary packages .rpm, .deb)

Comment: Actually, it may not be because of it needing old versions. The development VMs they use where we got this use Fedora7, not Centos7. I'm not even sure what the differences entail, but getting a Fedora VM up at my workplace is not a trivial task, but also not out of the question if it needs to be done.

Comment: OK, Fedora 7 *is* old: 2007-05-31 . Very old! Are you sure you mean Fedora **7** ? ?

Comment: You know, I'd ask them, but they're on a business trip till the 24th. I should have it in my email though.

Comment: Ok, I checked it out. They're actually using Red Hat 7.4 according to what they said previously. Is this a versioning difference? If so how would I correct this assuming that I cannot switch OS? If it cannot be fixed without switching it'll be a while before I can switch.

Comment: Redhat EL 7 and "Redhat CentOS 7.4" : Identical OS´s → No reason to switch OS. ... About your error : `-lcurl` is not an EXTRALIB. Please try removing `-lcurl`, to have this only : `EXTRALIBS= /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a`

Comment: Actually I'm using Centos 7.5.1804, they're using RHEL 7.4. I don't know if that makes a difference. I tried removing -lcurl from extra libraries. It did not make a difference, but it also didn't revert back to the old error either.

Comment: »»I don't know if that makes a difference«« : Actually RHEL 7.4 is now 7.5, if they updated packages with `yum update`. About curl : Are you sure the application uses the 64 bits curl? Worth a try : `yum install libcurl-devel.i686`

Comment: I did that and it did not seem to affect anything.

Comment: Just  a thought : When libxerces-c must be static ( `libxerces-c.a` ), may be your "app" is hard coded to look for `libcurl.a` only ?

Comment: I would just like to follow up. I found out the cause for the error. The app apparently was made for a different version of Linux. It was corrected by "yum install redhat-lsb"
How would I go about adding this correct answer to the answer you gave in order to make it complete and also highlight the fact that the answer is situational?

Comment: Ref. "The app apparently was made for a different version of Linux"  → → Add to my answer : I can do that when you tell which  "different version of Linux". ... Or better : you can just add the solution to your question.

Comment: I wish I knew which version of Linux it was made for honestly. Apparently though the Government uses this program on a different flavor than it is being developed on. What flavor is unknown to me, as well as why this is the case. I'm just an intern.